# Look up speed in Generic

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, generics, performance

I need to implement a search algoritm with efficient o(1). If I use HashSet and will try search by User.FirstName for example, whether it is right? If not, give me an advice, please, how can I realize this search?

Comment: you probably want a `Dictionary<string, User>` instead.

Comment: @Ben: Not if you're using FirstName, as you'll get duplicate keys...

Comment: @Reed: True, you want something along the lines of `unordered_multimap`... I don't think any is provided by .NET.

Comment: @Ben: `ILookup<T,U>/Lookup<T,U>` - See my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, where the `TKey` is built on the search type.  However, if you're using something like `FirstName` as a search term, you may have multiple values with the same key, which will cause problems.

A potentially better option would be to use [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) to generate an `ILookup` for you.  For example:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = GetPeople();

var nameLookup = people.ToLookup(p => p.FirstName);
```

You could then do:

```
var peopleNamedFred = nameLookup["Fred"];
foreach(var fred in peopleNamedFred)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}, fred.FirstName, fred.LastName);
```

Comment: LookUp is immutable. That's nice for some uses, but makes it unusable for others.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: True - you'd have to regenerate the `ILookup` if your data changes.  That being said, you could always make your own ILookup using `Dictionary<T, List<U>>` if required.

Answer (score 0):

Create an implementation of `System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`.
According to the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx) it " provides both O(1) indexed retrieval and keyed retrieval that approaches O(1)."  However, it still has the limitations that `Dictionary' and`HashTable` have with duplicate keys not being allowed.  If you need duplicate key values, or you need to be able to use different items as keys at different times, then Reed Copsey gives a very good solution.